# How to check which button clicked and also pass id from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list in my view and each row in my list contains view or submit buttons based on the status. It the application is complete then View button else Edit&Submit button. When a user clicks any button I need to check which button clicked and redirect the action to the respective controller.  The challenge here is how do I pass which button clicked and also the id from view to controller?

View :

This only passes which button clicked to the controller. But also I need to pass id. without passing id I cannot display any data in my Edit&Submit page and View pages.

```html
@if (@list.Completed == true)
{
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="btn" type="submit" name="View" id="View" value=View>View</button>

    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="col-md-2 ">
        <button class="btn" type="submit" name="EditSubmit" id="EditSubmit" value=EditSubmit>Edit&Submit</button>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CompleteList(string View, string EditSubmit, int mylistid)
    {
        if (View == "View")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Viewcontoller", "Primary");
        }
        if (EditSubmit == "EditSubmit")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("EditAndSubmit", "Secondary");
        }
        return View();

    }
```

Is there any way I can pass id as well as button clicked to controller and perform the actions inside one ActionResult ?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, the value of the EditSubmit property in the CompleteList method is the value property of the button. This is mapped based on the name of the button. So, if you set the value equal to an ID, that is was will be received in the controller. For example, in the button definition below, the controller method would receive the value of "12345" in the EditSubmit parameter.

```
<button class="btn" type="submit" name="EditSubmit" id="EditSubmit" value="12345">Edit&Submit</button>
```